# Error when installing "gem install bundler --no-doc" using a shell script

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, rubygems, rvm

I am creating a script on Debian 11 with a regular user.

I'm trying to run this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

rvm install ruby-2.7.2

gem install bundler --no-doc
```

However, when I try to run the command:

```bash
gem install bundler --no-doc
```

It returns the following error:

```bash
gem: command not found
```

But if I install it manually by typing directly into the console:

```bash
rvm install ruby-2.7.2
```

I don't have this problem when I run:

```bash
gem install bundler --no-doc
```

The problem occurs when the command "rvm install ruby-2.7.2" is executed through a script. Does anyone know what the problem is and how to resolve it?

It seems that the script doesn't load the environment variables of the user who executed the script. I tried using:

```bash
su -c "/tmp/script.sh" - username
```

But it gives an error saying that I don't have permission
Even though the script has permissions for the user.

Comment: When I use the script to install Ruby, the output of the command `whereis -b gem` is empty:
`gem:`

But when I install it using the terminal, the output of the command `whereis -b gem` is:
`gem: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.7.2/bin/gem`

Comment: One more thing I discovered is that when I do the installation directly in the terminal, the following path is created: `/usr/local/rvm/gems/default/environment`.

However, when using the script, the `default` folder is not created: